# How to Copy the (ASCII) alphabetic characters contained in an existing string into a new one

Tags: c, string, pointers, char, ascii

The new string should contain only the alphabetic characters from the existing string in the same order. Non-alphabetic characters should be not be copied. If s is a null pointer, return a null pointer.

Example input: 
"Ready... aim... fire!"
Output: 
Readyaimfire

I don't know why in my first for loop, the code never enters the if statement. I'm also not sure if I allocated the memory for the new string correctly. Thanks for any help :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *alphabetic (const char *s);

char *alphabetic (const char *s)
{
    char *newChar;
    int i;
    char n = 0;
    long length = strlen(s);
    for(i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        if( (s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z') ||  (s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z') )
        {
                n++;
        }
    }
    newChar = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*n);
    for(i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        if( (s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z') ||  (s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z') )
        {
            newChar[i] = s[i];
        }
    }

    return newChar;
}

int main (void)
{
    char *a, *b, *c;
    a = alphabetic ("Ready... aim... fire!");
    b = alphabetic ("***");
    c = alphabetic ("*a*b*c*");

    printf ("%s\n", a);
    printf ("%s\n", b);
    printf ("%s\n", c);

    free(a);
    free(b);
    free(c);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are using `char n = 0;` it should be of `int` type. because of that it is not allocating memory.

Answer (score 0):

The conditional of the first `if` and the conditional of the second `if` are such that if one is `true` then the other is `false`. Hence, you never get to the line

```
n++;
```

You need

```
if ( (s[i] <= 122 && s[i] >= 97) || (s[i] <= 90 && s[i] >= 65) )
```

To make the code more readable, you can make it:

```
if ( (s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z') ||  (s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z') )
```

If you have the option of using the standard library, you can just use:

```
if ( isalpha(s[i]) )
```

BTW, the line

```
    s = s + i;
```

is going to mess things up. As you iterate through the loop, you'll end up skipping parts of the input string. Remove that line.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use a single loop of that

```
int j = 0;               //take integer variable
for(i=0; i<length; i++)
{
    if( (s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z') ||  (s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z') )
    {
         //n++;     //Remove this
         newChar[j] = s[i];
         j++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Things about your code:

- n should be n+1 to accommodate '\0' character
- 2nd for loop: you need to have another variable say j =0 and incremented on every match. You can't use i for the newChar array as in the original array s,since i might point to an address that's outof bounds in the newChar array.For ex: ready...aim, newchar # elements 8 while s =11

  So saying newChar[8]=s[8] is wrong,rather it should be newChar[5]=s[8].

Posting the corrected code:

```
char *alphabetic (const char *s)
{
char *newChar;
int i,j=0;       //Change1: extra variable j to keep a track of elements for newChar
char n = 0;
long length = strlen(s);
for(i=0; i<length; i++)
{
    if( (s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z') ||  (s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z') )
    {
            n++;
    }
}

newChar = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(n+1));       // Change2: n+1 instead of n


for(i=0; i<length; i++)
{
    if( (s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z') ||  (s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z') )
    {
        newChar[j++] = s[i];       //Change3: j instead of i
    }
}
newChar[j]='\0';       //Termination of strings

return newChar;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I can't tell you why your code doesn't enter the if statement because you didn't provide the test case (input data) on which the algorithm does not enter the if statement. What I can tell you is that it won't do what you want it to do. Let's break down the for loop for a moment here:
it says "make variable i = 0, then, while i is smaller then the length of char array s, do some stuff then increment i". This is a very handy way to parse a char array. That's just fine and dandy, but inside the for loop, the first instruction is s = s + i. What that will do is move the pointer s forward by i characters at each iteration. Keep in mind that i will increase with time. Say we give that function the char * "This is a sentence.". The function strlen(s) will return 19 (which will be stored in length) and thus the for loop will iterate 19 times, with i taking values from 0 to 18 including. Let's see what's happening to s in there. First time, *s value is T. When you make s = s + i (i = 0), *s will still be T. T's ascii code is 84 and the if checks for values between 97 and 122 (including). So that's that for the first iteration. Then i becomes 1. And s moves one position further, thus *s will be 'h'. The ASCII code for the letter h is 104, so it enters the first if (because it is beween 122 and 97). Then, you ask if s[i] is beween 90 and 65. Now, because you incremented s, *s is 'h', but i == 1 at this point and thus s[i] is actually 'i' (whose ASCII code is 105 and thus never entering that loop). So if you wanna increment your n with your given algorithm I would say you need an input test case looking like so: "ThIsiSaSENtENCE". What you want is a clean string parsing for loop with another clean if to check whether the current character is a letter:

```
for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
    if((s[i]<='Z' && s[i] >= 'A') || (s[i]<='z' && s[i]>='a'))
      n++;
  }
```

This will count how many letters are there in your char array s.

EDIT:
If you wanna remove those characters which are not letters and return the new string then you might wanna try something like this (NOT OPTIMAL):

```
char *copyStringByLetter(char *arg, int size)
{
    int i = 0;
    int n = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        if((s[i]<='z' && s[i]>='a')||(s[i]<='Z' && s[i]>='A'))
            n++;
    }
    char *result = malloc(n+1); //need #include <stdlib.h>
    if(!result){
      fprintf(stderr, "Error alocating memory!");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE) //you need #include <stdlib.h> for this
      }
    int j = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
        if((s[i]<='z' && s[i]>='a')||(s[i]<='Z' && s[i]>='A')){
            result[j] = s[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    result[j] = '\0' //terminate the array
    return result;
}
```

If you want to ask me why I am sending the length of char array as an argument, it is to prevent char overruns (who happen more often than you might think)